# How can i precompile a YUI.template.Micro to a TemplateName.js file?

Tags: javascript, templates, yui

I have been reading up on using YUIs template.micro here:
 [precompiling YUI micro templates](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/template/#precompiling-and-reviving-micro-templates)
but cant see how its possible to return the JS to a templateName . js file.
Alternatively, if its not designed to be saved to a templateName . js file - how is it designed to be used?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs show you how to precompile but it lacks the part where you save it to disk.

Here's a slightly modified example

```
// Load the YUI Template.Micro module.
var Micro = require('yui/template-micro').Template.Micro;

// Precompile a template string (pass any string you like here).
var precompiled = Micro.precompile(fs.readFileSync("./template.tmpl"));

// Save the compiled template to disk
fs.writeFileSync("./template.js", precompiled);
```

That last step is the important one.

Comment: Thanks Tivac - much appreciated! Ill give it a shot and let you know shortly.

Comment: Would you by any chance also know how to load it once its saved? Im trying to understand there example here: [defining templates in a module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/template/#defining-templates-in-a-module) to no avail... thanks so much for your answer above in any case...